# How to get return from Single in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I want to return true or false from Single.fromCallable{} in RxJava.Is there any other way to achieve it

```
private isBlockListAvailable():Boolean
{

Single.fromCallable {
        //** data base query
        blockRepo.getAllBlocks()
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({blockList : List<BlockList>
                if (blockList> 0) {
                    return true // how can i achieve this
                } else {
                   return false // how can i achieve this
                }
            })
}
```

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: you cannot do this. You probably want to `.subscribe()` in the method that calls `isBlockListAvailable()` instead, so you can use the boolean there directly

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant. It's impossible to return value in the subscribe method. Look detail at its implementation.

```
Single.subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String s) throws Exception {

                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
```

You can see the method accept of the Consummer class is a type of void. Obviously, it cant return value.

Another way, you can create Single.fromCallable if you prefer to manipulate boolean in subscribe.